# Mongodb: Maintaining timestamp from existing _id but modifying machine & pid

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I was storing data received from an API in Mongodb, and just realized the data was containing an _id, so that, while doing the insert, Mongodb did not create an objectid but inserted the string _id I receive.

So now, I want to convert from string _id to objectid. What is the best strategy to do so?

1. new_oid = ObjectId(string_id) - timestamp is maintained but machine id & pid coded in the string_id will not be consistent with my server & pid that store the data
2. new_oid = ObjectId() - timestamp is lost, but machine id & pid coded in new_oid will be consistent with the server that actually stored the data

Thanks!

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. What is the "string" you are receiving? Is it representative of an ObjectId value or not?

Comment: Yes, The string _id I receive -for example 544c89e1d73ee8330a0002ed- is representative of an ObjectId.

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem you are presenting. Casting the string value to an `ObjectId` will simply result in that binary type being represented from the string value. There are no "local" substitutions being performed. The string "hex" value is taken as a literal.

Comment: As far as I understand, string & objectid _id both encode the timestamp along with machine & pid. If I do ObjectId(string_id), the data stored in my Mongodb will contain a valid timestamp, but a machine id that do not match my server and a pid that do not match the program that inserted it in Mongodb. This is my problem.

Comment: Is what you are being asked really that hard to work out? What is the problem? So a hex string from an external source does not represent the machine you are inserting from. So what? You want to change this on byte values? Then go ahead, it's well documented. This just reeks of misplaced concern for something you don't understand. So it it better that you **fully** state what your real concern is or do some more reading on the subject.

Comment: @antoinet: You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624116/how-can-i-import-data-to-mongodb-from-json-file-using-java/26628201#26628201. With a few adaptions, this should help you.

Comment: @NeilLunn I was just wondering how to maintain the timestamp & update the machine & pid to match with my app. Btw, having a lot of reputation does not give you right to say that what I say reeks.

Comment: It's a figure of speech not an insult, so apologies if you are not familiar with the English vernacular that I am used to. What you were asked to do on several occasions was "edit" and clarify your question. If you see fit to "upvote" a comment pointing you to another existing question (haven't read it, but I did say "modify the byte parts" (sic) ) so that would imply a duplicate question, No?

Comment: I voted up for a comment that could bring a potential solution (but unfortunately does not). I will clarify my question just now.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Interesting but I don't see how to modify machine & pid while leaving the timestamp untouched in your question.

Comment: As I said: you need to modify. In the Id setter, create a new ObjectID from the string, get the timestamp, use it to create a new ObjectID from that and set the property accordingly. I refuse to write the actual code for you. BTW: Neil is right. There is no reason to change the ObjectID in the first place.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I never asked for the actual code to be written for me - and never will. Your code imports a json into an object in Java - I'm using Python or Mongodb shell in Javascript. So I can't use your resources in Java, and it would be too time consuming to create a class matching the json object I receive. But thanks anyway for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new_oid = ObjectId(string_id)` is fine. It doesn't matter if machine id and process id do match.

While it's possible to extract some information from ObjectIds, I wouldn't rely on it in production code.

---

**About timestamps**

The timestamp isn't really a business value, it's the time when the document was inserted into the database, whereas you want to know for example the time an order was received.

Besides that [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) doesn't guarantee good timestamps:

> The relationship between the order of ObjectId values and generation
>   time is not strict within a single second. If multiple systems, or
>   multiple processes or threads on a single system generate values,
>   within a single second; ObjectId values do not represent a strict
>   insertion order. Clock skew between clients can also result in
>   non-strict ordering even for values, because client drivers generate
>   ObjectId values, not the mongod process.

Therefore I use the timestamp property of ObjectId sometimes during development as a convenient method to find the lastest documents, but don't really care about the content of it.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer Thanks, this answers the original question & shows that updating machine & pid is kind of useless since they only help to maintain some kind of unicity (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/W_cVvRe-lpc). Your answer also shows that the question was not requiring clarification, so I deleted the edit. Best!